# Remove Port identification from TFS url

Tags: tfs

we recently installed TFS and our users have asked us to remove the port identification from the url. I am not too familar with iis and tfs, is there a specific setting i have to change in the bindings to allow this change? The iis server we have will only host TFS no other applications will be hosted there.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 80 port for the TFS site. As the 80 port is the default http port, it doesn’t need to be specified.

So, just add a new binding with the port 80. (Make sure the 80 port is not used by other processes)

***To change/add the bindings:***

1. Open **Start** > **Administrative Tools** > **Internet Information
   Services (IIS) Manager**.
2. In the Connections tree expand the computer and then **Sites**.
   Click on the **Team Foundation Server**.
3. In the Actions pane click "**Bindings...**"
4. Click **Add** to add a new binding to bind the port **80**
5. Restart the site, try the url without port specificed (e.g.:
   `http://server/tfs`)

After that you can also change the **Public URL** in TFS Administration Console if needed.

Refer to Mummy's blog - [Detailing TFS configuration – IIS](http://blog.majcica.com/2016/03/07/detailing-tfs-configuration-iis/) for details.

[image]